# Labels above tikz tree forks

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees

I have an upward-growing tree showing the flow of a proof, as follows:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}

\begin{document}
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[edge from parent path=
  {(\tikzparentnode.north) .. controls +(0,1) and +(0,-1)
                                    .. (\tikzchildnode.south)}]
  \node {L5. $(A)\rightarrow(A)$} [grow'=up] %node[above]{MP}
    [sibling distance=60mm]
    child {node {L3. $(A)\rightarrow((A)\lor(A))$}
      child {node {P2. $(x)\rightarrow((x)\lor(y))$}}
    }
    child {node {$((A)\rightarrow((A)\lor(A)))\rightarrow((A)\rightarrow(A))$}
      child {node {L4. $((\lnot(A))\lor((A)\lor(A)))\rightarrow((\lnot(A))\lor(A))$} edge from parent[dashed]  
          [sibling distance=80mm]
          child {node {L1. $((A)\lor(A))\rightarrow(A)$} edge from parent[solid] 
              child{node {P1. $((x)\lor(x))\rightarrow(x)$}}}
          child {node {L2. $(((A)\lor(A))\rightarrow(A))\rightarrow(((\lnot(A))\lor((A)\lor(A)))\rightarrow((\lnot(A))\lor(A)))$} edge from parent[solid]
              child{node {P2. $(x)\rightarrow((x)\lor(y))$}}}}
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{document}
```

[image: Tree diagram]

I want to place a short, small label ("MP") immediately above the "L5." and "L4." forks (above the brackets, not between the bracket and the statement), but adding nodes in all the places I've tried breaks the graph in various ways. Am I just adding the nodes wrongly, or do labels like that need to be treated separately from the tree (through explicit placement, etc.)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a solution where internal label (L4) and (L5) are added for those two nodes in the tree. Then use `\node` command with `above` option at the end of the tree to place the label `MP`.

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}

\begin{document}
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[edge from parent path=
  {(\tikzparentnode.north) .. controls +(0,1) and +(0,-1)
                                    .. (\tikzchildnode.south)}]
  \node (L5){L5. $(A)\rightarrow(A)$} [grow'=up] %node[above]{MP}
    [sibling distance=60mm]
    child {node {L3. $(A)\rightarrow((A)\lor(A))$}
      child {node {P2. $(x)\rightarrow((x)\lor(y))$}}
    }
    child {node {$((A)\rightarrow((A)\lor(A)))\rightarrow((A)\rightarrow(A))$}
      child {node (L4) {L4. $((\lnot(A))\lor((A)\lor(A)))\rightarrow((\lnot(A))\lor(A))$} edge from parent[dashed]  
          [sibling distance=80mm]
          child {node {L1. $((A)\lor(A))\rightarrow(A)$} edge from parent[solid] 
              child{node {P1. $((x)\lor(x))\rightarrow(x)$}}}
          child {node {L2. $(((A)\lor(A))\rightarrow(A))\rightarrow(((\lnot(A))\lor((A)\lor(A)))\rightarrow((\lnot(A))\lor(A)))$} edge from parent[solid]
              child{node {P2. $(x)\rightarrow((x)\lor(y))$}}}}
    };
\node[above=0.6cm] at (L4){\small MP};
\node[above=0.6cm] at (L5){\small MP};
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you for the rapid reply.